# Combining WHERE EXISTS and IN in SQL

Tags: sql, db2, exists, relational-division

Consider there are n rows in table with a NAME and speciality.

```
NAME SPECIALITY
AA     X
AA     Y
BB     X
CC     X
CC     Y
CC     Z
```

I required names whose speciality included X and Y. As a result, I should get AA and CC. 
I come across where exists but i don't get to frame it right yet:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME
FROM SAMPLE
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT SPECIALITY
    FROM SAMPLE
    WHERE SPECIALITY IN ('X','Y')
);
```

This results in displaying all names. I couldn't crack it right. Could you please help understand?

Comment: sorry..that was a typo

Answer (score 1):

use aggregation

```
select name 
from tab
where SPECIALITY in ('X','Y')
group by name
having count(distinct SPECIALITY)=2
```

and in your query, i can edit like  below

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME
FROM SAMPLE t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT SPECIALITY  FROM 
             SAMPLE t2
             WHERE SPECIALITY IN ('X','Y') and
             t1.NAME=t2.NAME 
             having count(distinct SPECIALITY)=2
            );
```

Comment: having count(distinct SPECIALITY)=2 means?

Comment: @Gayathri it means for each name it will count  uniwue  SPECIALITY

Comment: for each name, it counts unique speciality? for a person, speciality isn't added twice, isn't it?

Comment: @Gayathri not getting you properly what you actually want to know

Answer (score 1):

You can use `self join` like the following:

```
select distinct t1.NAME from SAMPLE t1 join SAMPLE t2
on t1.NAME = t2.NAME 
and t1.SPECIALITY = 'X' and t2.SPECIALITY = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple `self` `join` on the table to get the desired output like following.

```
SELECT t1.NAME 
FROM   yourtable t1 
       INNER JOIN yourtable t2 
               ON t1.NAME = t2.NAME 
WHERE  t1.speciality = 'x' 
       AND t2.speciality = 'y'
```

Above query will show all the `names` having both the `speciality` `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS` like so:

```
SELECT name
FROM sample AS tx
WHERE speciality = 'x'
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM sample AS ty
    WHERE ty.name = tx.name
    AND ty.speciality = 'y'
)
```

It will find all `x` rows where a `y` row exists.

Answer (score 0):

`EXISTS` version requires two `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT S.*
FROM SAMPLE S
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SAMPLE S1 WHERE S.NAME = S1.NAME AND S1.SPECIALITY = 'X') AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SAMPLE S1 WHERE S.NAME = S1.NAME AND S1.SPECIALITY = 'Y');
```

However, simple aggregation should also work :

```
SELECT S.NAME
FROM SAMPLE S
WHERE SPECIALITY IN ('X', 'Y')
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING MIN(SPECIALITY) <> MAX(SPECIALITY);
```

Answer (score 0):

The relational operator you require is known as [divide](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) a.k.a. the supplier who supplies all parts.

SQL has no divide operator so you must roll your own, depending on a whether you want exact or remainders etc.

But if you will only ever have two hard-coded values then you can keep things a lot simpler:

```
SELECT NAME FROM SAMPLE WHERE SPECIALITY IN = 'X'
INTERSECT
SELECT NAME FROM SAMPLE WHERE SPECIALITY IN = 'Y'
```